# jQuery needed to expand height of select dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, select, scrollbar

I've used jQuery to add a 2 of option to a select element already containing about 20 options - after page ready().  A non-literal example:

```
<select>
  <option value='1'>Option already here</option>
  <option value='2'>Option added with jQuery</option>
  ...
</select>
```

This has worked fine, with the side effect of a scrollbar now appearing in my dropdown.

[example screenshot click here](http://imgur.com/HJ5CNH1)

How do I increase the size of the dropdown so all my options appear and no scrollbar is necessary?  Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I think this is impossible given that <select> is rendered differently based on the platform.

Comment: Kampai is correct.  Each browser will limit the max number options that will be displayed.
If you want to show more, then you will need a custom jQuery dropdown implementation, like Select2

Comment: Did you mean select with multiple Attribute? if as your html code above, it is a dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not do anything with original html dropdown, but  you can use some libraries to change the dropdown to another html element and do some tricks.

For example, you can use [chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), it transfer the `select` to a more beautiful, powerful `select`, also transfer it to a `div`, then you can change the height of it.

see [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f8K4c/)